# How do I convert a VirtualBox VDI file to a VMware vdmk?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware-player, virtual-disk

I'm using VirtualBox 2.1.4 and want to convert a VDI file to load it in VMware Player (3.0.0 build-197124 on Vista Home Premium).

I think I can change the VDI format to vmdk with a tool provided by VirtualBox:

```
VBoxManage clonehd /vboxdata/old.vdi /vmwaredata/new.vmdk -format VMDK
```

Its also possible to get a vmdk file with:

```
qemu-img.exe convert -O vmdk hdd.vdi hdd.vmdk
```

But this does not generate the vmx file that VMware Player need. How do I get that file?

---

For informational purpose, VMware Converter 4.0.1 says that the supported backup images or third-party virtual machines are:

> Microsoft Virtual PC 2004 or 2007
>
> Microsoft VirtualServer 2005
>
> Parallels Desktop 2.5, 3.0 or 4.0 for
>   Mac
>
> VMware Consolidated Backup
>
> Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery
>   6.5, 7.0, 8.0
>
> Symantec LiveState Recovery 3/6
>
> Norton Ghost versions from 9 to 14
>
> Acronis True Image Backup
>
> ShadowProtect Desktop, Server, SBS,
>   IT, etc versions from 2.0 to 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer from http://communities.vmware.com/people/pajegan

> You can use "VMware vCenter Converter
>   Standalone" to convert your VDI files
>   from virtualbox to .vmdk to use in
>   vmware server. The following are the
>   steps to do that:
>
> Make sure that your virtual machine in
>   virtualbox is up and running.
>
> Once you open the application, click
>   on "Convert Machine" and choose
>   Powered-on Machine.
>
> Choose remote machine
>
> Give the IP address, username and
>   password of the remote machine that
>   you would like to convert and then hit
>   next
>
> Select Destination Type as VMware
>   Workstation or other Vmware virtual
>   machine.
>
> Select Vmware product as Vmware Server
>   2.x
>
> Choose a location for the virtual
>   machine: It has to be a Network shared
>   folder.
>
> Hit Next and then check the settings
>   and hit next again.
>
> The task will take about an hour based
>   on the size of your virtual machine.
>
> Now you can copy the files to the
>   vmware server datastore and add the VM
>   to the inventory using the .vmx file.
>
> PS: I wanted to do the following steps
>   to use the Virtual machine in VMware
>   Esxi  server. However it is not
>   working in ESXi. If anyone has had
>   luck with migrating from Virtualbox to
>   VMware esxi, please let me know the
>   steps.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an updated answer as of version 5.0.14, shown below:

From the main window, click the File menu and select "Virtual Media Manager" or simply use the shortcut `Ctrl+D`.

[image: Main Window]

Select the disk you want to convert and click "Copy" or use the shortcut `Ctrl-O`.

[image: Virtual Media Manager]

Choose a path and filename for the converted disk, along with the file type, and click "Copy."

[image: Copy Virtual Hard Disk]

*Note: The source hard disk will already be selected if you chose it in the previous step.*

In my case, I converted a VDI of Windows Server 2016 TP4 into a VMKD for hosting in a corporate VMware environment. Both source and destination files were Dynamically Allocated.

Answer (score -1):

i think the only option is:

> 1) File->Export Appliance...
>
> 2) select the VM you want to export
>
> 3) save it(.ova file) to a backup folder somewhere (with a different name
>   from the original perhaps)
>
> 4) use OVF 1.0 format and write a manifest file (2.0 does not work)
>
> 5) wait until export is finished and then import/open to VMware (for more
>   waiting:)

because it seems that VMware does not like to import regular .vmdk files...

> 6) so the best option is to always use a .vdmk format in VirtualBox
>   too?