# How do I convert a Virtualbox drive to VMware drive?

Tags: virtualbox, conversion, vmware-workstation

I have a Virtualbox drive that I'd like to convert to a VMware drive. The problem is that my disk size is dynamic, meaning that the maximal size is 2 TB! I don't have enough disk space to convert the drive to raw data as described at http://www.trippholden.com/?p=48.

Any suggestions on how to convert my drive to VMware? I'll be using workstation 6.5.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/73470/virtualbox-vdi-file-to-vmware

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/197423).

> Reading through the comments of the
>   blog you show, I saw the most elegant
>   solution. Just need to use VirtualBox
>   itself: Excerpted from VirtualBox User
>   Manual version 2.14, page 108:
>
> `VBoxManage clonehd <uuid>|<filename> <outputfile> { -format VDI|VMDK|VHD|RAW|<other> } { -remember }`
>
> format: Allow to choose a file format
>   for the output file different from the
>   file format of the input file.
>
> Remember: Keep the destination image
>   registered after it was successfully
>   written.