# how to connect virtual box os and local machine

Tags: vmware, virtualbox

This question is in connection to this question asked by a user before:
[How do I convert a VirtualBox VDI file to a VMware vdmk?](https://superuser.com/questions/73470/virtualbox-vdi-file-to-vmware)

On how to convert vdi to vmdk or vmx using vmware converter.

How do I connect the windows xp that is in virtual box to the local computer (windows 7) in a network.

Because I got this error while I tried following this instruction:

```
Give the IP address, username and password of the remote machine that you would like to convert and then hit next
```

I got this error in vmware converter:
Unable to connect the specified host `10.0.2.15` which is the ip address of the xp machine inside virtual box.

It also said that there is a network configuration problem.
And when I inputted the ip address from whatismyip.com which should be the same as the ip address on local machine. I didn't get the previous error but I got another one, it said that:
insufficient permissions to connect to "ip address"
What solution can you suggest for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another virtual networking adapter in bridged networking mode; this helps communicate with all devices that are connected to your router.

Answer (score 0):

From the guest IP address it looks like your using a NAT network for the guest OS. This will make it difficult to access from the host. You could try changing the adapter type to Host only or bridged.

To do this select the VM and choose Settings/Network and change the adapter type. This should allow you to communicate more easily between the host and guest.

failing that you will have to port forward between the host and guest, details of which can be found in the NAT section of the Virtualbox help.

Comment: what adapter type would I choose?